# Bug or meant to be: numpy raises "ValueError: too many boolean indices" for repeated boolean indices

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am doing some simulations in experimental cosmology, and encountered this problem while working with numpy arrays. I'm new to numpy, so I am not sure if I'm doing this wrong or if it's a bug. I run:

```
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.3-1 (32-bit)

Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-1 (32-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 11:28:34) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> t = np.arange(10)
>>> t[t < 8][t < 5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many boolean indices
>>>
```

I expected it to return:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

since t[t < 8] should presumably be treated as just another ndarray?

The numpy documentation (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) says about boolean arrays as indices:

> As with index arrays, what is returned is a copy of the data, not a
>   view as one gets with slices.

running `type(t[t < 8])` also gives `ndarray`, which I guess should have all the properties of a numpy array. Should I perhaps do this better with list expressions? I have not done a timed comparison yet, but I would imagine this to be a problem for large 2D arrays.

Comment: What exactly would you expect `t[t < 8][t < 5]` to return?

Comment: Sorry, edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: @plan -- do you understand the difference between a 'copy' and a 'view' in terms of numpy arrays?  the term 'copy' can be misleading.  A `view` shares memory with the parent.  `a = np.arange(10); b = a[5:]; b[0] = 42; print a`.  `b` is a *view* into `a` even though they have different shapes.  (i.e. mutating `b` also mutates `a`).  If we do a similar operation that gives a "copy" instead of a "view" it meas we have a seperate array that doesn't share memory with the first.

Comment: Not sure but I think I do better now. A view is still the original data, which allows me to do, for example, `t[0:5][3:5]
`. Which was the total opposite of what I first thought about copies/views. Thanks for the observation @mgilson.

Answer (score 7):

`t[ t < 8 ]` does indeed give you an array, however, it doesn't give you an array of the same size that you started with.  `t < 8` will give a boolean array with the same shape as `t`.  When you use that to index `t`, you pull out only the elements where the boolean array is `True` leaving you with a shorter array.  When you do that again:

```
result = t[t<8]
result[t<5]
```

Then the boolean index array is the same shape as `t` once again, but you're using it to index a smaller array which is what causes the error.

The documentation is completely correct.  Your new array isn't a `view` into the original ... It is a copy of the data, but that doesn't imply that the new array is the same shape or size as the original.

Comment: Ha, it seems "too many boolean indices" doesn't refer to the number of times you tried to access elements with boolean indexing, but rather the length of the boolean index array.

Comment: @askewchan -- exactly.  I didn't even think of interpreting the traceback differently ... maybe because of my familiarity with numpy.  Now I see the confusion.

Comment: Yes, for me it was a very confusing traceback, does it make sense in some deeper way or is it just confusing?

Comment: @plan -- It makes sense to me.  It's saying that your array (`t < 5`) is an array with too many "boolean indices" to index the other array (`t[ t<8 ]`) because the other array is too small.

Comment: Yes, I guess I just didn't think of that `t < 8` is just a boolean array, since I only use boolean arrays as indices.

Answer (score 1):

This is meant to be. The reference to 't' is meaningless by the time you reach the second boolean statement. In the first statement you're segmenting t by values less than 8. In the second you're still segmenting 't', but on a temporary array (call it 's'). The index request on 's' can't always be mapped to 't' correctly. Thus it throws an exception.

If you want to do multiple boolean statements. Combine them so that it reads:

```
s = t[t < 8]
s[s < 5]
```

Or alternatively from @mgilson:

```
t[np.logical_and(t < 8, t < 5)]
```

Comment: you can't use the `and` operator like that.  You can use `np.logical_and(t<8, t<5)`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks, I should have thought of that. My question is answered. I have already used the method you suggested.

Comment: Yup I tried it right after I posted and immediately changed it